# Checking if item is in ConcurrentDictionary without getting back the value

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

`ConcurrentDictionary` has `public bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value)` for checking if particular key is in the dictionary, but I really don't need the `out TValue value`. Just want to know if the key is in the dictionary.

Technically, I can use `Item` property, but it has to be wrapped-up in `try/catch` clause.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It also has ContainsKey which satisfies your requirement.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287082(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
        var dict = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();

        if (dict.ContainsKey("KEY"))
        {
            //do some work
        }
        else
        {
            dict["KEY"] = "VALUE";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like [`ContainsKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287082(v=vs.110).aspx) is what you want.